# General motion of a cone on an inclined surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

> Suppose that a solid cone is placed horizontally on an inclined surface and is initially at rest. How will the cone move when it starts motion due to its weight?

I know that its motion depends on the incline angle and also on the friction coefficient of the surface (as I observed by doing some experiments), but I can't establish the relation between them. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is friction infinite, finite with stick and slip, or zero?

Comment: The coefficient of friction is not zero, but it can assume any value other than that.

Comment: So the cone rolls sometimes, and slips some other times. This makes the problem much more difficult to deal with.

Comment: The simplest solution is when friction is zero, the cone will slide in a straight line. The 2nd most complex case is pure rolling (infinite friction) and the most complex is slip/roll combination. What where you looking for?

Comment: Since its a non-symmetric body, about a horizontal line I think position of center of gravity will also affect the motion the cone undergoes.

Comment: Is the cone upright on the surface and sliding, or laying on the surface and rolling.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

"How will the cone move when it starts motion due to its weight"

to answer this equation you have to obtain the equations of motion.

you have 3 generalized coordinates

- rotate about then z -axis angle $\psi$
- incline plane x position $s_x$
- incline plane y position $s_y$

thus you get :

**Kinetic energy**

$$T=\frac 1 2\,{{\it \dot{s}_x}}^{2}m+\frac 1 2\,{{\it \dot{s}_y}}^{2}m+\frac 1 2\,{\dot{\psi}}^{2}{{\it J_z}
}^{2}-\tau_z\,\psi
$$

Where $\tau_z$ is the torque due to the friction forces and $J_z$ is the inertia of the cone z component.

**Potential  energy**

$$U=m\,g \left( \sin \left( \alpha \right) {\it s_y}+{\it s_z} \right) $$

Where $s_z$ is the z component of the  COM.

Thus: The EOM's:

$$m\,\ddot{s}_x+F_{Rx}=0$$
$$m\,\ddot{s}_y+F_{Ry}+m\,g\,\sin(\alpha)=0$$
$$J_z^2\,\ddot{\psi}+\tau_z=0$$

with $\tau_z=F_{Ry}\,y_s\quad $ and $F_{Rx}=\mu\,N\,,F_{Ry}=\mu\,N\quad , N=m\,g\,\cos(\alpha)$

According to the EOM's the cone will move "diagonal" on the incline plane and rotate about the cone z- axis

Answer (score 0):

For a solid cone the COM is $\frac{h}{4}$ above its base

Along the incline we can write the following equations.

Forces:
$$Mg\sin\theta+f=Ma$$

Torque:
$$\frac{fh}{4} = I \alpha$$

In this case $I = \frac{3}{5}m(\frac{r^2}{4}+h^2)$

Rolling:
$$\alpha = \frac{a}{h/4}$$

Since we have 3 equations and 3 unknowns $(f, a, \alpha)$  the system can be solved.

Comment: Using math formatting by enclosing expressions with `$...$` makes any post far more readable. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cone will not move in a straight line, it will try to rotate around its apex while going down the plane.